# InfoPath 2013 Multi Selection List Count

Tags: infopath, count, choices

I want to thank you in advance.

I've been doing the search and found something close but did not work.

I have a 'multi selection list box' created in InfoPath with 8 items in it.

The box is called, "group1" and when applied a rule to show the count,

it only shows "1" even though I selected 5.

Some post had ' count(preceding-sibling::my:mlstSubCategory'

I don't see preceding-sibliing in my 'Insert Function' (is this built in command?)

So, that did not work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count XPath expression on the values of the group1:

```
count(../my:group1/Value)
```

However it seems it always return +1 so you should change above expression to:

```
count(../my:group1/Value) - 1
```